# SSIS deployment issue

Tags: excel, ssis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running an SSIS Package using dtexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088974/running-an-ssis-package-using-dtexec)

My SSIS package is working fine when I'm running it on my local system. My Package copies a blank template excel file which has only headers, to another place, and then populates this copy with data from the DB. However, when i place the package and config on the server, and schedule an SQL server job on it, it's throwing errors as follows :

```
Executed as user: CIQHYD\sqladmindev. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package UtilityVersion 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bitCopyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
Started: 3:24:28 PM
Error: 2012-10-29 15:24:28.34 
  Code: 0xC001401E 
  Source: GICSReport Connection manager "GICSReport.xls" 
  Description: The file name "\\HYD-FILESVR\Departments\Technology\GICSReports\Dev\GICSReport.xls" specified in the connection was not valid.
End Error
Error: 2012-10-29 15:24:28.34 
  Code: 0xC001401D 
  Source: GICSReport 
  Description: Connection "GICSReport.xls" failed validation.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started: 3:24:28 PM
Finished: 3:24:28 PM
lapsed: 0.234 seconds 
[SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000). The step failed.
```

When I delete the file at the Destination folder, i get this error :

```
Executed as user: CIQHYD\sqladmindev. 
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bitCopyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005. All rights reserved.
Started: 3:15:38 PM
Error: 2012-10-29 15:15:38.57 
  Code: 0xC001401E 
  Source: GICSReport Connection manager "GICStemplate.xls" 
  Description: The file name "\\HYD-FILESVR\Departments\Technology\GICSAutomationTemplate\GICStemplate.xls" specified in the connection was not valid.
End Error
Error: 2012-10-29 15:15:38.57 
  Code: 0xC0202070 
  Source: GICSReport Connection manager "GICStemplate.xls" Description: The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.
End Error
Error: 2012-10-29 15:15:38.57 
  Code: 0xC0029163 
  Source: Copy Template To Destination File System Task 
  Description: File or directory "\\HYD-FILESVR\Departments\Technology\GICSAutomationTemplate\GICStemplate.xls" represented by connection "GICStemplate.xls" does not exist.
End Error
Error: 2012-10-29 15:15:38.57 
  Code: 0xC002F30A 
  Source: Copy Template To Destination File System Task 
  Description: The source is empty.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started: 3:15:38 PM
Finished: 3:15:38 PM
Elapsed: 0.344 seconds [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000). The step failed.
```

Comment: To clarify : I'm deploying my package as a T-SQL task in an SQL Server Job. This task essentially runs a command line call to DTEXEC, passing the package name and config file.

Comment: It's not a permissions issue, because even when I change the job's owner to myself instead of the sqladmindev, it still throws the same error.

Comment: To clarify, you are not having a *deployment* issue with your package. You are have an *execution* error. A deployment issue would manifest as unable to copy an SSIS package to (SQL Server, File System or SSIS Package Store)

Comment: Duplicated by the same user... Thanks @billinkc for the lookup!

Answer (score 1):

```
Version 10.0.4000.0 for 64-bitCopyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-2005.
```

Did you try to run it in 32-bit mode?

http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.nl/2012/09/swtich-package-from-64bit-to-32bit.html