# SSIS add Custom Header to Excel file

Tags: excel, ssis, excel-interop, sql-server-agent, windows-security

We are dumping data into an excel file using SSIS. Need to add a Custom Header to the Excel file.

The code below worked for many years. (on Different Windows (Win7,Win10) and different office versions (Office2007 and Office2013).

```
        string ExcelTarget = Dts.Variables["ExcelTarget"].Value.ToString();
        int ReportDayDiff = (int)Dts.Variables["ReportDayDiff"].Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelTarget, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["Orders"];
        xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1";
        xlWorkBook.Save();
        xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&B&\"Calibri\"&22 SellerCloud Orders - " + DateTime.Now.AddDays(ReportDayDiff).ToString("MM/dd/yyy");

        xlWorkBook.Save();
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); // first parameter is SaveChanges
        xlApp.Quit();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Stooped working after a recent Windows Security Patch Update.

Runs fine in Visual Studio, but errors out in SQL Server Agent.

Error from SQL Server Agent

> Executed as user: Office\Administrator. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  3:01:22 PM 
>   Error: 2018-05-16 15:01:25.64     Code: 0x00000001     Source: Script
>   Task      Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned
>   DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  3:01:22 PM  Finished: 3:01:25 PM 
>   Elapsed:  2.687 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step
>   failed.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

This exception is general, i think you should add some error handling to the script code to get the real exception.

But i think that this is a reference issue, the sql agent may not be able to access the `microsoft.interop.excel.dll` path, or this assembly should be re-installed in GAC.

There is some similar article that contains more details and workarounds:

- [Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation - SSIS Script Task Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762220/exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation-ssis-script-task-erro)
- [Script task error: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/210a6900-633e-4fec-80e4-0575a276f4d0/script-task-error-exception-has-been-thrown-by-the-target-of-an-invocation?forum=sqlintegrationservices)